# Universal Google Analytics on/off line syncing

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-analytics

we have a angularjs app and we want to track the android users way of using it in the fields. This app can be used for 2-3 days off-line and sync opportunistically when wi-fi connections or 3g-4g are available.

Our goal is to track user behaviour with UA and cache usage data to send at first wifi opportunity.

1. Does UA have a built-in support for this?

if not

1. Can we do this programatically using v3 apis? ie. cache data locally and use a service to sync the data if online?

In either case, how much data can UA cache?
How many days can the data stay cached locally before syncing?

Cheers,
T

Answer (score 0):

While UA has support for this the support does not extend to multiple days - [according to the parameter reference for the measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt) (which is the basis for UA) "queue time" is four hours at max.

Using the API (which is built on top of the measurement protocol) will not change that.

Comment: Is it possible to cache UA collected data locally using the UA apis?